Justification for equality in partial fraction expansion from generatingfunctionology by Herbert S. Wilf
The problem is from generatingfunctionology by Herbert Wilf on page 4. My question is not about the process of getting the generating function (they do a good job in this post) but rather where the justification that
$$ \frac{x}{(1-2x)(1-x)} = x\left\{ \frac{2}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x} \right\} $$
is obtained via partial fraction expansion (decomposition). For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out the trick.
So far, I've tried p.f.e. and this is what I get:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{x}{(1-2x)(1-x)} &= \frac{A}{1-2x} + \frac{B}{1-x} \\
x &= A(1-x) + B(1-2x) \\
1 &= A(1-1) + B(1-2) \implies B = -1 \\
x &= A(1-x) - (1-2x) \\
A(1-x) &= 1-x \implies A = 1\\
\end{aligned}$$
This means that
$$\begin{aligned}
x \left( \frac{2}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x} \right) = \frac{1}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{aligned}$$
Which is true, after a little bit of algebraic manipulation.
Desmos is convincing enough for me to show that they're equal, but I'm lookin' for the juice. In other words, is it really just creative manipulation or am I missing something obvious?

Just separate out the $x$, apply p.f.e. to the remaining fraction, $\frac1{(1-2x)(1-x)}$. Doing the same method you did, you will find $\frac1{(1-2x)(1-x)}=\frac2{1-2x}-\frac1{1-x}$. Finally, multiply back in the $x$ which was separated at the start.

Doh! Feel free to enter that as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Just separate out the $x$, and apply p.f.e. to the remaining fraction, $\frac1{(1−2x)(1−x)}$. Doing the same method you did, you will find $\frac1{(1−2x)(1−x)}=\frac2{1−2x}−\frac1{1−x}$. Finally, multiply back in the $x$ which was separated at the start.
